Unexpected error moving a file on an SFTP server using Spring Boot. Also possible major problem, is it a bug?
I have the following code.
SftpConfig.java
package com.smiler.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;

@Configuration
public class SftpConfig {

    @Bean
    public DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory() {
        // using free SFTP server generated by
        // https://sftpcloud.io/tools/free-sftp-server
        // these only last for 60 minutes so you will need to generate another one or
        // change the bits below to one you already have available
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost("eu-central-1.sftpcloud.io");
        factory.setPort(22);
        factory.setUser("1a372bdd0e9c4dda98d20330d897d050");
        factory.setPassword("VTT7ueYCygGIFTNncIvrCNfXZnI1wCI2");
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }
}

SftpMoveFileConfig.java
package com.smiler.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.gateway.SftpOutboundGateway;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpRemoteFileTemplate;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;

@Configuration
public class SftpMoveFileConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel sftpMoveFileChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpMoveFileChannel")
    public SftpOutboundGateway sftpOutboundGateway(SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate) {
        SftpOutboundGateway gateway = new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpRemoteFileTemplate, "mv", "payload");
        gateway.setRenameExpressionString("headers['destinationPath']");
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory) {
        return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(sftpSessionFactory);
    }
}

SftpFileMover.java
package com.smiler.demo;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component()
public class SftpFileMover {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SftpFileMover");

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel sftpMoveFileChannel;

    public void moveFile(String sourcePath, String destinationPath) {
        logger.info("Move " + sourcePath + " to " + destinationPath);
        sftpMoveFileChannel.send(
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(sourcePath)
                        .setHeader("destinationPath", destinationPath)
                        .build());
        logger.info("Moved");
    }
}

SftpMoveFileRunner.java
package com.smiler.demo;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.smiler.demo") // Include the package where your components are

@Component
public class SftpMoveFileRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("SftpMoveFileRunner");

    @Autowired
    private SftpFileMover sftpFileMover;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        logger.info("Here we go!");
        logger.info("sftpFileMover = " + sftpFileMover);

        String sourcePath = "/Source.png";
        String destinationPath = "/Destination.png";
        sftpFileMover.moveFile(sourcePath, destinationPath);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Run");
        SpringApplication.run(SftpMoveFileRunner.class, args);
    }
}

When run with the file Source.png present, the following error is logged.
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'sftpOutboundGateway' for component 'sftpOutboundGateway.serviceActivator'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/smiler/demo/SftpMoveFileConfig.class]'; from source: 'com.smiler.demo.SftpMoveFileConfig.sftpOutboundGateway(org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpRemoteFileTemplate)']
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:390) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:361) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:331) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:304) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at com.smiler.demo.SftpFileMover.moveFile(SftpFileMover.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.smiler.demo.SftpMoveFileRunner.run(SftpMoveFileRunner.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at com.smiler.demo.SftpMoveFileRunner.main(SftpMoveFileRunner.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: no output-channel or replyChannel header available
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:531) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:359) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:288) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:252) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:151) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        ... 32 common frames omitted

Do I need to configure the solution to no expect a reply header? If so, how? If not, then what changes do I need to make the code?
If I run it again without recreating Source.png and just leave Destination.png in place, a File not found error is logged, quite reasonably. See below. However, the file Destination.png is deleted. This is not what I would expect? Do I need to make changes to prevent this happening or is it a bug?
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'sftpOutboundGateway' for component 'sftpOutboundGateway.serviceActivator'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/smiler/demo/SftpMoveFileConfig.class]'; from source: 'com.smiler.demo.SftpMoveFileConfig.sftpOutboundGateway(org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpRemoteFileTemplate)']
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleWithMetrics(AbstractMessageHandler.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:70) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:148) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:121) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendInternal(AbstractMessageChannel.java:390) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.sendWithMetrics(AbstractMessageChannel.java:361) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:331) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:304) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at com.smiler.demo.SftpFileMover.moveFile(SftpFileMover.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
        at com.smiler.demo.SftpMoveFileRunner.run(SftpMoveFileRunner.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.12.jar:6.1.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:342) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.3.jar:3.3.3]
        at com.smiler.demo.SftpMoveFileRunner.main(SftpMoveFileRunner.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:459) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.executeMv(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:776) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.doMv(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:750) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:589) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:145) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.sshd.sftp.common.SftpException: no such file
        at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.throwStatusException(AbstractSftpClient.java:277) ~[sshd-sftp-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkResponseStatus(AbstractSftpClient.java:264) ~[sshd-sftp-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkResponseStatus(AbstractSftpClient.java:246) ~[sshd-sftp-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.checkCommandStatus(AbstractSftpClient.java:233) ~[sshd-sftp-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.impl.AbstractSftpClient.rename(AbstractSftpClient.java:666) ~[sshd-sftp-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.apache.sshd.sftp.client.SftpClient.rename(SftpClient.java:617) ~[sshd-sftp-2.12.1.jar:2.12.1]
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.rename(SftpSession.java:185) ~[spring-integration-sftp-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.mv(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:808) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.gateway.AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.lambda$executeMv$12(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.java:777) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:450) ~[spring-integration-file-6.3.3.jar:6.3.3]
        ... 37 common frames omitted

The pom.xml file used is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.smiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

I tried running the code above as explained. I would have expected the file to be moved (which did happen) but did not expect an error to be logged.
I certainly didn't expect the destination file to be deleted if the code was run when the source file didn't exist.
